# Wrong digest value using PHP

Tags: php, xml, soap, digest

I've got string:

```
$string = '<Predstavitev xmlns="http://www.sigen.si/PodpisaniDokument" Id="MyVisualisation2"><Podatki ca="SIGEN-CA" dsPodjetja="" dsUporabnika="12345678" emso="1212912500444" maticna="" serial="2462933412018"/></Predstavitev>';
```

and digest value of it should be

```
tmLGK3IVc1mC/r5ScUKXQ46wcCA=
```

but when I use this PHP code

```
echo base64_encode(hash('SHA1', $string, true));
```

the output is

```
yszGh284QybUiyVNLfQlkh358qQ=
```

In SOAP is reference for canonicalization method (http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315) and digest method algorithm (http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1).

Thanks for help!

Comment: How did you find that `tmLGK3IVc1mC/r5ScUKXQ46wcCA=`?

Comment: It's written in example (https://storitve-ca.gov.si/Soap.xml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the digest value is wrong and the functions applied are correct, then the input value is wrong - and not the digest. The digest is correct in the sense that it's correct from the wrong input value.

Therefore you need to apply the standards as you've named them (canonical form, digest) on the input you've got.

If you're too lazy to do that your own, you can for example take an existing library for that which is able to parse the algorithms from the [soap-response XML](https://storitve-ca.gov.si/Soap.xml)  you've got:

```
$string = '<Predstavitev xmlns="http://www.sigen.si/PodpisaniDokument" Id="MyVisualisation2"><Podatki ca="SIGEN-CA" dsPodjetja="" dsUporabnika="12345678" emso="1212912500444" maticna="" serial="2462933412018"/></Predstavitev>';

$sig = new XMLDSig($soapResponse);

var_dump($sig->getDigest($string)); // string(28) "tmLGK3IVc1mC/r5ScUKXQ46wcCA="
```

The **XMLDSig** class is part of [XMLUtil](https://github.com/hakre/XMLUtil/), also on packagist, just require ["hakre/xmlutil": "dev-develop"](https://packagist.org/packages/hakre/xmlutil).

Answer (score 0):

You need to `canonicalize` the string before doing the hash.

Just add the string to a DomDocument and get the C14N from element `Predstavitev`:

```
$string = '<Predstavitev xmlns="http://www.sigen.si/PodpisaniDokument"     
Id="MyVisualisation2"><Podatki ca="SIGEN-CA" dsPodjetja="" 
dsUporabnika="12345678" emso="1212912500444" maticna="" 
serial="2462933412018"/></Predstavitev>';

$xml = new DomDocument();

$xml->loadXML($string);

$node = $xml->getElementsByTagName('Predstavitev');

echo base64_encode(hash('SHA1', $node->item(0)->C14N(), true));
```

Comment: Just use your $string value. Mine was empty.